# PHP Convert DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS to Monday, 1st Jan 2015

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a date as follows in the DB: `14/6/2015 00:00:00`

I would like to change this to `Sunday, 14th June 2015`

I tried the following but no luck. Any advice?

```
$dateStart = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'startdate' , true); // 14/6/2015 00:00:00
$dateStart = date('l, d F Y', strtotime($dateStart));
$dateStart = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'startdate' , true);
$dateStart = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s', $dateStart);
$dateStart = $dateStart->format('m/d/Y');
$dateStart = date('l, d F Y', strtotime($dateStart));
```

I have tried other threads such as [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php) and followed what they have said but it just doesn't work for me, unless I am missing something very obvious

Comment: You need to use `createFromFormat` since that is a non-standard format and `stringtotime` chokes on it.

Comment: Fixed it but it seems a lot of work for something so simple - updated

Comment: Get rid of your last 2 lines and just use `$dateStart = $dateStart->format('l, d F Y');`

Comment: Thanks - still seems like a lot of work :-( might look to updating SQL

Comment: The problem is that `d/m/Y` is not a standard date format.  `m/d/Y` is for the US and `d-m-Y` for Europe/others.

Comment: Based in the UK and we only ever use dd/mm/yyyy - not to worry - thanks for the help